# What are the main differences between classes and structs in swift 3?

Tags: swift, class, struct

The only thing I found is that a struct cannot inherit but a class does, and that a struct is passed by value while a class is passed by reference, but I couldn't understand what is that exactly.
Can someone explain it please or give me an example?

Comment: Major: classes are reference type while Struct are value type

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
class Car {
    var name: String

    init(name:String){
        self.name = name
    }
}

var carA = Car(name: "BMW")
var carB = carA
//now I will change carB
carB.name = "Nissan"
print(carA.name) //This will print Nissan


struct CarStruct {
    var name: String

    init(name: String){
        self.name = name
    }
}

var carC = CarStruct(name: "BMW")
var carD = carC
//now I will change carB
carD.name = "Nissan"
print(carC.name) //This will print BMW
```

As you can see both `CarA` and `CarB` are pointing to the same reference so if one changes the other change because the reference is changing, while in `CarC` and `CarD` which are structs they are copies of each other each with its value.

Answer (score 1):

According to the very popular WWDC 2015 talk Protocol Oriented Programming in Swift [video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=408), Swift provides a number of features that make structs better than classes in many circumstances.

Structs are no more limited to just a set of fields holding some values.

Instead, Swift’s structs have quite the same capabilities as classes — except inheritance — but instead are value-types (so copied every time you pass them in another variable, much like Int for example) whereas classes are reference-types, passed by reference instead of being copied, like in Objective-C.